# Finding random seed used

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

I have some code I am where the positions of some particles are randomly generated. Normally I generate them randomly using numpy.random.seed however had commented this out. Is there a way to be able to recreate the system I just used or find out the seed of the randomly generated numbers from the simulation I just ran?